# What is meant by the Grothendieck group being the "best possible" construction of an abelian group from a commutative monoid?

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, grothendieck-construction

On the wiki page for [Grothendieck group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group#Explicit_construction), the first sentence says the Grothendieck group is the "best possible" way to construct an abelian group from a commutative monoid.

What actually does this mean formally?

Comment: It means it satisfies a universal property. In this case, the Grothendieck group of $M$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) abelian group $G$ and a homomorphism $M \to G$ such that every monoid homomorphism $M \to H$ with $H$ a group factors uniquely through $M \to G$.

Comment: Paolo Aluffi has a nice (elementary) discussion of the Grothendieck group in Algebra Chapter 0. I recommend that you check it out.  The exercises deals with some elementary instances of it too.

Comment: @Dedalus Can you please share the link of the note of Paolo Aluffi?

Answer (score 8):

Statements like this usually refer to universality. Note that given a monoid $M$ the Grothendieck group $G$ comes with a map of underlying monoids $s:M\to G$.

Now given $H$ an abelian group and $f:M\rightarrow H$ a map of underlying monoids. Then there exists a unique group homomorphism $g:G\to H$ making the diagram commutative, i.e $g\circ s=f$. This also makes $G$ unique up to isomorphism.

You will find universal properties of that kind at many places in mathematics.

Addendum: The following more or less reflects my personal taste and therefore might or might not be helpful. Whenever I see a universal property I don't fully understand, I convince myself that it makes sense in a simpler setting I can grasp better. So if you want to replace the words *monoid* by *subset of $\mathbb R^n$*, *homomorphism* by *inclusion* and *group* by *closed set*. What is the closed set which approximates a given arbitrary set in the best possibly way? Does this satisfy a similar universal property?

Comment: +1 for your explanation of universal property via topology!